# Laravel 4 send email from localhost to gmail

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I am unable to send an email from my locally developed site..In my controller I have the following code :

```
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all();

    Mail::send('contact.display',$data, function($message)
    {
        $message->to('giannhs905@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
}
```

And my view is below:

```
<h1>    
Subject : {{$data['subject']}}
</h1>   

<h1>
From : {{ $data['name'] }}
</h1>
<br/><br/>

{{ $data['comments'] }}
```

Initially I don't care about Inputs given in my form..I just want to send a dummy email to my account...

What am I doing wrong? Should I change some config. files..?

Comment: Did you modify the mail settings in the config folder?

Comment: No...should i do it..?If so,what should i change

Comment: Sure. Check the config file there. The comments explain what to put there.

Comment: Can tou help me a little bit...i am new in web development and i am a little lost...if i make the changes it will work or i should have a mail server also..?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/mail#configuration explains how to configure this. Mostly you can use the smtp server from you isp.

Comment: I don t have an isp for my site...i run it locally

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43593/discussion-between-jackpoint-and-john)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your `config/mail.php` file.

If you have a gmail account, you can use googles mail driver. Use it like so:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => '*your@gmail.com*',
'password' => '*yourpassword*',
```

Comment: Ok...I made it work...But I cannot access data in my view...I get $data not defined..I update my code above and wait for your reply..Thank you

Comment: Use: $message->subject= $data['subject']; And in your view: {{ $message->subject }}

Comment: I get Undefined variable: data again..Any ideas..?

Comment: Yes, but this isn't related to your initial question anymore. Anyway, try this: $data['comments'] = Input::get('comments');

Mail::send('contact.display',$data, function($message) use ($data)
{
$message->to('giannhs905@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome!');
$message->comments = $data['comments'];
});  But, i only see a very small part of your code, so the problem could be a lot of things right know(like your form). Maybe you should post a new question with the full code and description of your 'new' problem.  *edit: typo